# blueimg file upload plugin response codes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I am using the fileupload plugin "blueimg file upload" from here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.

It suggests few error shown below:

```
window.locale = {
    "fileupload": {
        "errors": {
            "maxFileSize": "File is too big",
            "minFileSize": "File is too small",
            "acceptFileTypes": "Filetype not allowed",
            "maxNumberOfFiles": "Max number of files exceeded",
            "uploadedBytes": "Uploaded bytes exceed file size",
            "emptyResult": "Empty file upload result"
        },
        "error": "Error",
        "start": "Start",
        "cancel": "Cancel",
        "destroy": "Delete"
}
};
```

but, how can I throw these errors. 
for example: can I check the max file size on the server side then responses the corresponding error code to the blueimg plugin on the client.

And moreover, I want to inject a more error mappings to it. 
How to get it done?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set maxFileSize, minFileSize, acceptFileTypes, etc as options when using file upload widget.

In the add function of the file upload initialization, you can check like this.

```
add: function (e, data) {
  $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
    if (file.error === 'maxFileSize') {  
        $('#errorMessage').html('<a class=\"close\" onclick=\"closeAlert(\'errorMessage\');\">×</a>' + fname +  ': File size larger than allowed. Please upload a smaller file.');
    } 
    else if (file.error === 'acceptFileTypes') {
        $('#errorMessage').html('<a class=\"close\" onclick=\"closeAlert(\'errorMessage\');\">×</a>' + fname +  ': Invalid file type. Please select a valid file.');
    } 
    else if (file.error === 'minFileSize') {
        $('#errorMessage').html('<a class=\"close\" onclick=\"closeAlert(\'errorMessage\');\">×</a>' + fname + ': Cannot upload empty file.');
    }
  });
}
```

the file upload plugin does all the check and gives the error back based on the options set.